# What is the use of bootstrap and ini files and give me some exp?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I am new to zend framework I would like to know about bootstrap.php and .ini files and can you explain me with one example?

with database example also ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from official [ZF quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html), I could recomend you to have a look at [Tutorial: Getting Started with Zend Framework 1.10](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/). You could also check out free book: [Zend Framework Book: Surviving The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) and [ZendCast](http://www.zendcasts.com/).

Edit. By request of the OP in the comments below, I paste some example of Bootstrap.php and an ini file:

**Bootstrap.php**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    // set a doctype for the Zend_View    
    protected function _initDoctype() {
        $view = $this->bootstrap('view')->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }

    // add path to my view helpers
    protected function _initHelperPath() {
        $view = $this->bootstrap('view')->getResource('view');
        $view->setHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers', 'My_View_Helper');
    }

    // read appkey.ini and save it to registry for later use
    protected function _initAppKeysToRegistry() {

        $appkeys = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/appkeys.ini');
        Zend_Registry::set('keys', $appkeys);
    }

}
```

**appkeys.ini**

```
; facebook and twitter app keys obtained after registering your app
; with these two websites.  

facebook.appid = YOUR_FACEBOOK_APPID
facebook.secret = YOUR_FACEBOOK_SECRET
facebook.redirecturi = http://url.of.your.app/
facebook.scope = 'email'

twitter.appid = YOUR_TWITTER_APPID
twitter.secret = YOUR_TWITTER_SECRET
twitter.redirecturi = http://url.of.your.app/
```

Comment: I studied that one and i created on example that is loginform without any bootstrap and ini files...so why we need these files and give me once example?

Comment: @kiran. Which one did you study that does not have Bootsrap.php and ini files?

Comment: yes we have but the problem is why should we use that files without that files also our exmaple is running..

Comment: @kiran. the ini and bootstrap files are used for configuration and initiation of zF resources. You don't need to use them, but if you for example, what to set locale for your application you would do it in your ini or your bootstrap. Otherwise, the ZF will use only default values or resources, which may not be suited for everyone.

Comment: @Marcin..Can u have one sample Example contains bootstrap.php and .ini files?

Comment: @kiran. I added examples. Hope they will be useful.

Comment: @kiran. Glad to help. Anyway if you find my answer acceptable, I would be grateful for an accept.